# How to join objects in array according to custom rules in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have an array like this

```
[ { color: 'blue', type: '+', amount: '1' },
  { color: 'blue', type: '-', amount: '1' },
  { color: 'blue', type: '+', amount: '24' },
  { color: 'red', type: '+', amount: '10' },
  { color: 'red', type: '-', amount: '1' },
  { color: 'red', type: '-', amount: '1' },
  { color: 'red', type: '-', amount: '2' } ]
```

and I would like to group by color and type, and sum the amount. The result should be like this:

```
[ { color: 'blue', type: '+', amount: '25' },
  { color: 'blue', type: '-', amount: '1' },
  { color: 'red', type: '+', amount: '10' },
  { color: 'red', type: '-', amount: '4' } ]
```

Is there a good/right way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using `reduce` method:

and the code looks like this:

```js
const data = [
       { color: 'blue', type: '+', amount: '1' },
       { color: 'blue', type: '-', amount: '1' },
       { color: 'blue', type: '+', amount: '24' },
       { color: 'red', type: '+', amount: '10' },
       { color: 'red', type: '-', amount: '1' },
       { color: 'red', type: '-', amount: '1' },
       { color: 'red', type: '-', amount: '2' }
    ];

    
    const result = [...data.reduce((r, o) => {
      
      const key = o.type + '-' + o.color;
    
      const item = r.get(key) || Object.assign({}, o, {
          amount: 0
      });
    
      item.amount += +o.amount;
    
      return r.set(key, item);
    }, new Map).values()];
    
    console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

Using a combination or Array#reduce and Map can solve this problem.

Use the color and type as an idea.

*This could probably be simplified more*

```js
const data = [ { color: 'blue', type: '+', amount: '1' },
  { color: 'blue', type: '-', amount: '1' },
  { color: 'blue', type: '+', amount: '24' },
  { color: 'red', type: '+', amount: '10' },
  { color: 'red', type: '-', amount: '1' },
  { color: 'red', type: '-', amount: '1' },
  { color: 'red', type: '-', amount: '2' } ];
  
const reduced = data.reduce((acc,{color, type, amount})=>{
  const amountNum = Number(amount);
  const key = `${color}:${type}`;
  if(acc.has(key)){
    const old = acc.get(key);
    return acc.set(key, {color, type, amount: amountNum + old.amount});
  }
  return acc.set(key, {color, type, amount: amountNum});
}, new Map());

const res = Array.from(reduced).map(([,item])=>item);

console.log(res);
```